# Поиск в списке по имени ( когда даны имя и фамилия) Python

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Как посчитать количество имён? (print выводит по нулям)

```py
students = [ 'Круглов Алексей' ,'Ворожейкин Борис','Митин Сергей','Алёшин Сергей',
              'Кутиков Владимир','Круглов Денис','Бочкин Иван','Мечников Алексей']
 
students.sort()
 
students.count('Сергей') 
students.count('Денис')
students.count('Алексей')
 
print(students.count('Сергей')) 
print(students.count('Денис'))
print(students.count('Алексей'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Нули выводятся, поскольку вы считаете имена в элементах списка, а их в "чистом" виде нет - они с фамилиями. Поэтому совпадений нет.
Один из быстрых вариантов - объединить элементы списка в одну строку и считать имена уже в ней:

```
students = ['Круглов Алексей', 'Ворожейкин Борис', 'Митин Сергей', 'Алёшин Сергей', 'Кутиков Владимир', 'Круглов Денис',
            'Бочкин Иван', 'Мечников Алексей']

joined = ' '.join(students)

print(joined.count('Сергей'))
print(joined.count('Денис'))
print(joined.count('Алексей'))
```

```
2
1
2
```

Другой вариант - перебрать все элементы списка в цикле и посчитать в них. Результат тот же:

```
sergey = denis = alexey = 0
for fio in students:
    sergey += fio.count('Сергей')
    denis += fio.count('Денис')
    alexey += fio.count('Алексей')

print(sergey, denis, alexey, sep='\n')
```

Вариант 3 - разбить элементы исходного списка по пробелам и сделать новый список, где имена и фамилии будут отдельными элементами, затем посчитать:

```
splitted = []
for fio in students:
    splitted.extend(fio.split())

print(splitted.count('Сергей'), splitted.count('Денис'), splitted.count('Алексей'), sep='\n')
```